# Fast UITableViewCell with a UIWebView ？

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview

Problem：Fast UITableViewCell with a UIWebView

1. Using UITapGestureRecognizer achieve UIWebView click event,but when click link in UIWebView, UITapGestureRecognizer and Link event will be triggered. How to solve it？
2. cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

   ```
   UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
   singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
   singleTap.view.tag = indexPath.row;
   singleTap.delegate = self;
   singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
   [cell.wvContent addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; // cell.wvContent is UIWebView
   ```

Click on any row will be repeated trigger multiple times，how to solve it？

Comment: For future reference, code should be wrapped in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Its not advised to use webview within tableview cell. Both classses are inherited from scrollview :)

Comment: How to display html content?